# regarding brp card

Tags: resident-permit

Yesterday, I went to collect my BRP, but the post office would not give it to me because of a spelling mistake on the BRP card. My visa is set to expire in a few days. I have already gone through the UK.gov website and raised the appropriate issue for the mistake but have yet to get a response. Will I still be considered legally present according my visa conditions?

And also want to know is this is the rule that post office person will be open that one?

Comment: Please do not SHOUT.

Comment: Also, could you reword your last question? I couldn't figure out what you're trying to say.

Comment: hi ouflak i just want to know that my biometric residents permits card is in post office where i m going to collect but they did not give me bcz there is a spelling mistake on my name on that.so in that case what should i do

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a purely administrative error then you will still be lawfully present in the UK when your visa expires. Despite that, you will want to get it corrected as soon as possible.